# Failed to load ngSanitize using angular cdn with the correct src

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, angularjs, ngsanitize

I'm new to angular JS...
I have

```
//HTML
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"


//JS
var app = angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize'])
```

However I received the error message : **"either I spelled ngSanitize wrong or forget to load it"**.
I'm sure the link is correct and my ngRoute has been successfully loaded... can anybody help me please?

Comment: what is order scripts are loading?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I changed the order to load sanitize first then views in index.html and it works!!